# What does '[Objectives 2012-13 Dave April13.xlsx]BU_Item1 i'!N5 mean in Excel

Tags: excel

Just got an excel spreadsheet with this in an if statement. N5 is a true or false value. I know this is probably stupid, but it's really hard to google and nothing else is coming up on here. Full if:

=IF(D28>0,'[Objectives 2012-13 Dave April13.xlsx]BU_Item1 i'!N5,0)

I know it is something to do with updating the values. But where are these values coming from (Because I can not see them in [Objectives 2012-13 Dave April13.xlsx] anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Excel is referencing to a workbook called `Objectives 2012-13 Dave April13.xlsx`, in the sheet  named `BU_Item1 i` and the cell `N5`.

If there's a warning about data connections and you enable them when you open the workbook, and this formula gives `#N/A`, it means that Excel cannot find that workbook either.

If you obtained the workbook from someone else, that person might know what is this file. Otherwise, not enabling the connection will allow you to see the value of that formula before excel actually traces the workbook being referenced.

Comment: +1 and ideally with a properly set up data connection `Objectives 2012-13 Dave April13.xlsx` would be a fully qualified path too